# difference between to and for

Tags: grammar, differences

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

A: The training course will give the opportunity for the teachers to enhance the understanding of emotional intelligence.

B: The training course will give the opportunity to the teachers to enhance the understanding of emotional intelligence.

Where the difference between both of them is the 8th word (for and To).

Comment: I would prefer 'The training course will give **an** opportunity to the teachers to enhance **their** understanding of emotional intelligence.'

Comment: No, but my question is why not "for the teachers" ?

Comment: Please look up the words in a good dictionary. See also [ell.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it looks like a matter of changing one word, in fact the two sentences have different structures. It happens in this case that there is no real difference in the meaning, but that will not always be so.

With *for*, "the teachers" goes with "opportunity", so:

> ... gives [to somebody unspecified] [an opportunity [for the teachers to ...]]

With *to*, "the teachers" goes with "give", so:

> ... gives [to the teachers] [an opportunity [for somebody unspecified to ... ]]

Answer (score 0):

To show a transfer, you would say you are giving an opportunity to the teachers. Think of it as "giving to" vs "giving for".  Couched differently, to show purpose, you could say the "the training course provides an opportunity for the teachers".
Here's another version that contrasts both:
The training course will give an opportunity to the teachers and provide critical information for their understanding of emotional intelligence.